# A formal word to mean " to decrease"

Tags: word-request

I look for a word that means " to decrease" which can  sound formal and fit the following context. For example can I use "to abate" ?

> When we use  body language correctly, the emotions and feelings that
>   we attached to words incarnate and become visible while the ambiguity of
>   words       ...............

Answer (score 1):

"...diminishes."

Correcting the subject-verb agreement slightly:

> When we use body language correctly, the emotions and feelings that we attach to words incarnate and become visible while the ambiguity of words diminishes."

From dictionary.com:

> to lessen; decrease

From using it as a native English speaker, "diminish" is probably the best word in the given context.

Answer (score 1):

Any one of the following would work in your context

> diminish
>   lessen
>   dissipate
>   decrease
>   recede
>   abate
>   are mitigated